# Why is pg_dump not dumping table contents?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

I am trying to take backup of a schema from a remote Postgresql server (Version:11.5). The below command used to take the backup works:

`pg_dump -CFc -h host -U user -d database -n schema -f "/path/data.backup"`.

Below is the verbose printed, which says the table contents are also dumped:

[image]

Besides, I am using Dbeaver tool to restore the backup into the postgresql server (Version:11.5) installed in my local machine. The restore works but the tables are empty.

Is there any other option which needs to be added, to export the data into the backup file ?

Comment: Try this https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/import-and-export-a-postgresql-database

Comment: If you look inside the dump file, do you see `INSERT` commands with your data?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein You mean `COPY` commands.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Data is present inside the dump file. This was confirmed when I loaded the dump into postgres server running on a linux machine ( the dump file export was done on a linux machine) . The dump import did not work on my local machine as it was running on windows.